# Python text processing/finding data

Tags: python, parsing, text

I am trying to parse/process some information from a text file using Python.  This file contains names, employee numbers and other data.  I do not know the names or employee numbers ahead of time.  I do know that after the names there is the text: "Per End" and before the employee number there is the text: "File:".  I can find these items using the .find() method.  But, how do I ask Python to look at the information that comes before or after "Per End" and "File:"?  In this specific case the output should be the name and employee number.

The text looks like this:

```
SMITH, John
Per End: 12/10/2016
File:
002013
Dept:
000400
Rate:10384 60
```

My code is thus:

```
file = open("Register.txt", "rt")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

countPer = 0
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    print (line)
    if line.find('Per End') != -1:
        countPer += 1
print ("Per End #'s: ", countPer)
```

Comment: `enumerate` helps you to access line and its index at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file = open("Register.txt", "rt")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

for indx, line in enumerate(lines):
    line = line.strip()
    print (line)
    if line.find('Per End') != -1:
        print lines[indx-1].strip()
    if line.find('File:') != -1:
        print lines[indx+1].strip()
```

enumerate(lines) gives access to indices and line as well, there by you can access previous and next lines as well

here is my stdout directly ran in python shell:

```
>>> file = open("r.txt", "rt")
>>> lines  = file.readlines()
>>> file.close()
>>> lines
['SMITH, John\n', 'Per End: 12/10/2016\n', 'File:\n', '002013\n', 'Dept:\n', '000400\n', 'Rate:10384 60\n']

>>> for indx, line in enumerate(lines):
...     line = line.strip()
...     if line.find('Per End') != -1:
...        print lines[indx-1].strip()
...     if line.find('File:') != -1:
...        print lines[indx+1].strip()

SMITH, John
002013
```

Comment: I try this code and I get this error:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
This will need to run off of a text file with multiple employees

Comment: yes, this did work for me for a text file with multiple employees. I created a sample text file based on your sample data in the question

Comment: Thanks. But how can I get around the error? " TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__' "

Comment: I found my mistake, corrected it, then received this error in it's stead:
"     print line[indx+1].strip()
Per End: 12/10/2016
IndexError: string index out of range"  The code is exact to yours at this point.  Not sure how to get around it.

Comment: how does your lines list look like? can you print it like I did it in my shell and put it here?

Comment: I don't necessarily have a "lines list".  I am trying to pull the data from a text file scraped from a .pdf.  The text contains about 100 employees all output in the same way as the sample that I gave.  I was hoping that it would go through this file and every time Per End was found, it would output the previous line which would be the employee name.  I know this probably doesn't help.

Comment: what I mean once you read it from file, after `readlines()`, you will have it in a python list. Does it print atlas few names and employee numbers or none?

Comment: This is a rough sample of my ouput:
['Reg\n', '\n', 'O /T\n', '\n', 'Hours\n', '\n', 'SMITH,JOHN\n', 'Per End: 12/10/2016\n', 'File:\n', '002013\n', 'Dept:\n', '000400\n', 'Rate:\n', '10384 62\n', '\n', '3&4\n', '\n', 'Reg\n', '10 384 62\n', '\n', 'O /T\n', '\n', 'Earnings\n', '\n', '3&4 Earnings\n', '40 85 TFB\n', '\n', '5\n', '\n', 'Federal\n', '\n', '10 425 47\n', '\n', 

It goes on a bit from there as well.  The output is pretty large as I am sure you can imagine.  There are about 100 total employees.

Comment: Ok, does it error out after printing few names or throwing error at first iteration itself.

Comment: I get this error directly after the "File:" text is located. 
SMITH,JOHN
Per End: 12/10/2016
d
File:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jjabbour/PycharmProjects/untitled/PDF-Text-Parser/ADP_Parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    print line[indx+1].strip()
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: There is typo in your code, please correct it. Its not `line[indx+1].strip()`, it is `lines[indx+1].strip()`

Comment: Thanks for that!!  This is an amazing help.

Comment: my pleasure!! thanks for providing all the data, which helped me to help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.

First, some test data.

```
test = """SMITH, John\n
Per End: 12/10/2016\n
File:\n
002013\n
Dept:\n
000400\n
Rate:10384 60\n"""

text = [line for line in test.splitlines(keepends=False) if line != ""]
```

Now for the real answer.

```
count_per, count_num = 0, 0
```

Using `enumerate` on an iterable gives you an index automagically.

```
for idx, line in enumerate(text):

    # Just test whether what you're looking for is in the `str`

    if 'Per End' in line:
        print(text[idx - 1]) # access the full set of lines with idx
        count_per += 1
    if 'File:' in line:
        print(text[idx + 1])
        count_num += 1

print("Per Ends = {}".format(count_per))
print("Files = {}".format(count_num))
```

yields for me:

```
SMITH, John
002013
Per Ends = 1
Files = 1
```

Comment: This works well but I will need to pull in data from a text file that includes multiple employees.  will this allow me to do that and print this result for each time it finds the specified strings?

Comment: sure. just change `enumerate(text)` to `enumerate(lines)` with your original `lines` being read in from a file. I just like to provide test data so that others can follow despite not having your original file - I'm too well trained to have tests :)